# Universal reference vs non-template `const&`

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

Consider the [following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nd5bYSgPV48rVpCc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class... Ts>
struct test {
    static void foo(const std::remove_reference_t<Ts>&...) {
        std::cout << "1\n";
    }

    template <class... Us>
    static void foo(Us&&...) {
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    test<int&, double&>::foo(1, 1.0);
}
```

The above code prints "2". Why is the second overload considered a better match?
The first one boils down to `foo(const int&, const double&)` and it's a regular function, so it should be preferred, shouldn't it?

I guess it's not an "exact match", but what is not "exact" here exactly?

Comment: What compiler are you using? gcc and clang [print 1](https://godbolt.org/z/Te5WE8).

Comment: Printing `1` for me https://godbolt.org/z/P69d7q

Comment: `Us&` - That's not a forwarding reference

Comment: Link in the question indicates some version of `g++` using the gnu extension to C++20.

Comment: It's printing `1` everywhere I try, except Wandbox.

Comment: Note that the code in the link doesn't match the code in the question.  The function in the question accepts `Us&...` while the one in the link accepts `Us&&...`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Yeah, and OP seems aware that the posted code should call 1. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @cigien It seems more like OP just typed the code in the question and is confused why the universal reference overload is preferred to the const reference overload.

Comment: @Miles Budnek oh, right, the code posted here had a typo, sorry. But the linked wandbox code is correct and prints 2 both with GCC and clang.

Answer (score 1):

A specialization of the second `foo` is prefered because of the way is specified template argument deduction and overload resolution.

Template argument deduction takes place only for the second `foo`.

`Us&&` is a **forwarding reference** [[temp.deduct.call]§3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#3.sentence-4)

> if P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

where `P` is the type of the function parameter [without cv qualifier and without reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#3.sentence-2). `A` is the type of the argument. An argument is an expression and expressions never have reference type. The first argument is a *prvalue* of type `int` and the second a *prvalue* of type `double`. A *prvalue* is not an lvalue so `P` is deduced to be `int` for the first argument and `double` for the second argument.

So after template argument deduction the second overload type is `void (int&&,double&&)`

The first overload has type `void (const int &, const double &)`.

After template argument deduction, the compiler must choose which of the too overloads is the best viable one. The list of rules is long but the difference happen to be that the implicit conversion sequences of the bindings of the materialized temporaries to the the reference parameters is better for the two argument bindings of the second overload than for those of the first overload [[over.ics.rank]§3.2.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2.3):

> S1 and S2 include reference bindings ([dcl.init.ref]) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference

Comment: It seems that 3.2.3 applies here (rather than 3.2.6), doesn't it?

Comment: @IgorR. Indeed and obviously.... you could have fixed it alone!

Answer (score -1):

The exact match is actually int&&, that’s why the second overload gets picked.
The reason is that a literal is a temporary, which can be used as an rvalue directly.
In the case where it’s used for const int &, the literal initializes another temporary which is used for the reference, by calling the move constructor (`int(int &&)`), akin to:

```
const int i = 1;
const double d = 1.0;
f(i, d);
```

Which would call the first overload.

Comment: _a literal is a temporary_ No. _the literal initializes another temporary which is used for the reference, by calling the move constructor (int(int &&))_ WHAT???

Comment: @LanguageLaywer: this is a simplification of binding a temporary to a const reference.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Can you elaborate on the literal not being a temporary?

Comment: `int` can't have a constructor, it's not a class. *"where it’s used for const int &, the literal initializes another temporary"* Source? I don't think there's an extra temporary.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#2.1

Comment: @HolyBlackCat an `int` or `double` literal is a prvalue whose value is that "encoded" by the literal, there is no object holding that value.

Comment: @Dani Notice how it doesn't speicify *what kind of* references, so lvalue- and rvalue-references should work the same way here. Also as Language Lawyer noted, prvalues are not actual objects, so there's only one temporary (per parameter). The whole point of the C++17 idea of temporary materialization (and the changes made to prvalues) is to get rid of unnecessary temporaries.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `int` or `double` (etc.) prvalues didn't have their values stored in objects even before C++17. E.g. in C++14: [An rvalue ... is an xvalue, a temporary object or subobject thereof, or **a value that is not associated with an object**.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.lval#def:rvalue) («An rvalue .. is a temporary object ...» — thanks RSmith this BS has been removed. I mean, rvalues are expressions and not objects.)